# Dell D600 with genuine win XP 64 bit / how to reuse the license?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Dell D600 withgGenuine XP 64bit license.

I don't have my dell restore CDs, how can I reinstall Windows XP and still use my current license?

Comment: Contact Dell and buy the restore media would work.  IS that not possible for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to get a copy of the CD.

You could torrent but, I don't think it is legal and you can't be promised of the quality of the data

You could buy the disk from [www.restoredisks.com](http://www.restoredisks.com) (cheaper than a new XP disc).

However, I would contact Dell direct and ask.